# How to write array with unsigned byte values to a binary file in PHP 5.6

Tags: php, arrays, file, byte, png

How can I write this array with unsigned bytes (0-255) to a binary file?

The array look like this:

*note that I did not add any index because PHP automatically add the value to the next available index in the array variable when you use []. So the first my_PNG[]=137; is the same as my_PNG[0]=137;. Next time [] is used the next index 1 is returned and so on and so forth*

```
my_PNG = array();
my_PNG[]=137;
my_PNG[]=80;
my_PNG[]=78;
my_PNG[]=71;
my_PNG[]=13;
my_PNG[]=10;
my_PNG[]=26;
my_PNG[]=10;
my_PNG[]=0;
my_PNG[]=0;
my_PNG[]=0;
my_PNG[]=13;
my_PNG[]=73;
my_PNG[]=72;
my_PNG[]=68;
my_PNG[]=82;
my_PNG[]=0;
my_PNG[]=0;
my_PNG[]=0;
my_PNG[]=1;
my_PNG[]=0;
my_PNG[]=0;
my_PNG[]=0;
my_PNG[]=1;
my_PNG[]=8;
my_PNG[]=6;
my_PNG[]=0;
my_PNG[]=0;
my_PNG[]=0;
my_PNG[]=31;
my_PNG[]=21;
my_PNG[]=196;
my_PNG[]=137;
my_PNG[]=0;
my_PNG[]=0;
my_PNG[]=0;
my_PNG[]=13;
my_PNG[]=73;
my_PNG[]=68;
my_PNG[]=65;
my_PNG[]=84;
my_PNG[]=120;
my_PNG[]=156;
my_PNG[]=99;
my_PNG[]=96;
my_PNG[]=96;
my_PNG[]=96;
my_PNG[]=248;
my_PNG[]=15;
my_PNG[]=0;
my_PNG[]=1;
my_PNG[]=4;
my_PNG[]=1;
my_PNG[]=0;
my_PNG[]=95;
my_PNG[]=229;
my_PNG[]=195;
my_PNG[]=75;
my_PNG[]=0;
my_PNG[]=0;
my_PNG[]=0;
my_PNG[]=0;
my_PNG[]=73;
my_PNG[]=69;
my_PNG[]=78;
my_PNG[]=68;
my_PNG[]=174;
my_PNG[]=66;
my_PNG[]=96;
my_PNG[]=130;
```

This is each byte in a PNG file with just one black pixel in it. 
I want to write or somehow save this array to a file so it can be used as an PNG image on the server.

I have tested:

```
file_put_contents('img.png', pack("C*",$my_PNG));
```

But it only save one byte to the file. I also tested a bunch of other things for the past 2 days now. So I finally wanted to get some help.

Comment: That's not an array.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: do you really need that many lines?

Comment: @KenWhite added my_PNG = array(); to show it's an array.

Comment: @PedroLobito 1 black pixel 1x1

Comment: Inserting a line at the top declaring it as an array doesn't change the fact you're not using it as an  array, and the way you're using it does not function the way you state it does. An array element is accessed using an index (subscript), such as `my_PNG[0]`, `my_PNG[1]`, etc.

Comment: @KenWhite added info about [] when dealing with arrays in PHP. That my_PNG[]=0 is the same as my_PNG[sizeof($my_PNG)]. sizeof($my_PNG) will return the count and use it as the next index. But [] do this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the input array is a byte array you just need to use
write it out as binary.

```
file_put_contents($filename, pack("C*", ...$my_PNG));
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. I should have checked that I needed to use ... to pack an array :-)