# Converting array bit into actual image

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, image, type-conversion

I have an array bit like this:

```
[255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 255, 219, 0, 67, 0, 1, 1, ...]
```

And I need to convert this into an actual image.

So I followed this python script that does the same and works properly:

```
file = x['data']['file']['file'] 

listRes = file.replace(' ', '')
listRes = listRes.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
listRes = listRes.split(',')
for i in range(len(listRes)):
    listRes[i] = int(listRes[i])
f = open('x.png', 'wb')
f.write(bytes(listRes))
f.close()
```

And this is my similar php code:

```
if(!empty($que["answer"]["file"])){
    $strbit = str_replace("[","",$que["answer"]["file"]["file"]);
    $strbit = str_replace("]","",$strbit);
    $strbit = str_replace(" ","",$strbit);
    $arrbit = explode(',', $strbit);
    for($j=0;$j<count($arrbit);$j++){
        $arrbit[$j] = (int)($arrbit[$j]);
    }
    $imageName = str_random(10).'.'.'png';
    \File::put(storage_path(). '/images/' . $imageName, ($arrbit));
}
```

But now the problem is that the exported image looks like this:

[image: capture]

Now instead of `\File::put(storage_path()...` I tried using `file_put_contents($imageName, pack("C*", ...$arrbit));` but it does not export anything at all!

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

---

**UPDATE #1:**

I tried this:

```
if(!empty($que["answer"]["file"])){
        $strbit = str_replace("[","",$que["answer"]["file"]["file"]);
        $strbit = str_replace("]","",$strbit);
        $strbit = str_replace(" ","",$strbit);
        $arrbit = explode(',', $strbit);
        for($j=0;$j<count($arrbit);$j++){
            $arrbit[$j] = (int)($arrbit[$j]);
        }
        $imageName = str_random(10).'.'.'jpeg';
        file_put_contents($imageName, pack("C*", ...$arrbit));
    }
```

But does not export any image and also not return any error!

Comment: You remove commas, while Python code splits string into array of numeric strings by comma. As to how write it to the disk, see the first answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44033739/how-to-write-array-with-unsigned-byte-values-to-a-binary-file-in-php-5-6) question.

Comment: I dont see the python code doing any base64 decoding, and the python code is saving as a mp4 and you're saving as a png

Comment: @alx I have updated the question would you mind check it out

Comment: @Dale I have updated the question would you mind check it out

Comment: In your last line of php code try this

`\File::put(storage_path(). '/images' . $imageName, (implode('', $arrbit)));`

I suspect if you open the file in a text editor you will the word `Array`

Comment: @Dale I tried that and again shows me the same small square that is shown in the question! I'm really stuck with this :(

Comment: probably need to find out what that python function `bytes` is doing and replicate that in php

Comment: @Dale It is similar to `chr` but chr() expects parameter 1 to be int, and in this case it's array given!

Comment: Please never present your sample data as a screenshot.  We prefer array data to be provided as `var_export()` output.  Doesn't Python have a json decoding function?!?  PHP does have  `array_map('intval', json_decode($que["answer"]["file"]["file"], true))`

Comment: @mickmackusa I removed the screenshot and added the data. And the python does not have any other function.

Comment: I think my comment still valid. Just tried this right now: `$arr = [255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 255, 219, 0, 67, 0, 1, 1, /* ... */];
var_dump(pack("C*", ...$arr));`, and output looks like JPEG (not PNG! it has "JFIF" header). So, given `$arr` is an array of numbers, doing the following will yield you a valid file: `file_put_contents('img.png', pack("C*", ...$arr));`. Make sure format matches extension, tho.

Comment: I see you edited your question, but you still don't use spread operator in `pack()` call. It is required, you need to write `pack("C*", ...$arrbit)`, otherwise it will try to render whole array of numbers as a single character.

Comment: @alx I run this code but don't export any image

Comment: Please see my comment above, you need to use spread operator: `pack("C*", ...$arrbit)`.

Comment: @alx I dont get what you mean by spread operator

Comment: @alx Now I'm using this line: `file_put_contents($imageName, pack("C*", ...$arrbit));` but does not export any image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247790/discussion-between-pouya-and-alx).

Comment: @alx Finally it worked out bro!! I tried changing the path and it worked out `file_put_contents(storage_path(). '/app/public/application/' . $imageName, pack("C*", ...$arrbit));` HOORA

Comment: @alx thanks man! You can add that as answer if you would like to. Also it would be best if you add some refrence to spread operator and `pack` that is used in file put contents. I haven't seen them till now

Comment: I see at least [this dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29919260/2943403) which points to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5473011/2943403)

Comment: Okay, glad to help, let me prepare a full answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, main issue was: how to convert input format -- string of comma separated character codes in brackets -- into binary form and write it to the file.

PHP has [`pack()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) function which fits this purpose nicely. Specifically, we need `C*` format as we are going to output raw 8-bit characters. So, given we have this input:

```php
$arr = [255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 255, 219, 0, 67, 0, 1, 1, /* ... */];
```

This is how we can convert it into a binary string (note the [`...` token](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) -- it is very important here, as `pack()` expects one argument per character converted, not an array as a single argument):

```php
$str = pack("C*", ...$arr);
```

Finally, original question was asking about `.png` files, but apparently the example data has `JFIF` header, which indicates `.jpg` format. If format is not known, one can use [`getimagesize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to guess it (note: the function requires file already written to disk, not a binary string with file contents).

Comment: Thanks once again, but one more question: does this work on `.mp4` video files also?

Comment: Yes, should work for any binary file.